# Word-VBA Loop on each page to export PDF

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have two tables on each page. I made a macro that copies strings in table(1), and then exports the file as pdf. This works very well. Now I want this macro to run on each page. But when I run the code, it just exports the first page as PDF.
My code is:

```
Sub string_String_Pending()
 Dim oTbl As Table
 Dim i As Integer

 Dim a
 a = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
 For i = 1 To a

   ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat 
   OutputFileName:=Left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(3).Range.Text, _
   Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(3).Range.Text) - 2) & " - " & 
   Left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(4).Cells(3).Range.Text, _
   Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(4).Cells(3).Range.Text) - 2) & ".pdf", 
   ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, Range:=wdExportCurrentPage

   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format your code. See [How do I format code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361)

Comment: Please, 1) use a title that names your problem, 2) add a vba-tag and 3) indent your code with 4 positions, so that it will be formatted as code. It will help us to thelp you and it will help people with the same problem to find the sollutions we propose.

Comment: Can you show some screenshots to explain better?

Comment: Please make two tables in word. Write anything in second table. In first table Row1,column3 write "Ashok". In first table Row2,column3 write "Jariwala". Copy both tables on second page. On second page, table(1),Row1,column3write "Ashok". and table(1),Row2,column3 write "Zariwala". In above code I change Row(4) to Row(2). Now run the code. My word page has two pages. I am suppose to get two PDF files exported to my default location. FIrst page as "Ashok - Jariwala" and second page as "Ashok - Zariwala". I only get "Ashok - Jariwala". I hope you may get my problem understand.

Answer (score 0):

Notice this bit of code in the method that saves as PDF:

```
Range:=wdExportCurrentPage
```

The problem with the code in the question is that it never moves to a different page.

There are various ways this could be done, but the simplest is to mimic the user pressing F5 ("Go to") and choosing to go to a specific page. I've added that at the end of the `For` loop. There are also `Debug.Print` statements that will show the page numbers in the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G in the VBA Editor) - you can comment these out or delete them.

I also added a line to make sure the code starts on the first page, which is necessary when doing something selection-based; and I changed the declarations of `i` and `a` to data type `Long`, which is recommended for "counters".

```
Sub string_String_Pending()
 Dim oTbl As Table
 Dim i As Long
 Dim a As Long

 a = ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
 Selection.HomeKey Word.WdUnits.wdStory

 For i = 1 To a

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat _
    OutputFileName:=Left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(3).Range.Text, _
    Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(3).Range.Text) - 2) & " - " & _
    Left(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(4).Cells(3).Range.Text, _
    Len(ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Rows(4).Cells(3).Range.Text) - 2) & ".pdf", _
    ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, Range:=wdExportCurrentPage
    Debug.Print Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Name:=i+1
   Next i
   Debug.Print Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me.There are also Debug.Print statements that you added and showed that when first page is selected it is exported as pdf. It then goes to second page. The Immediate Window (Ctrl+G in the VBA Editor) showed that page no. is 2. but then it goes to "next" command and saves the first page as PDF. I think it is "table(1)" that is creating problem.

Comment: If you're not actually selecting Table(1) then that shouldn't be affecting the page. I tested your code and it works for me. What I do notice, however, is that your code saves every file to the *same name*. Perhaps you should use the counter in the file name?

Comment: Please make two tables in word. Write anything in second table. In first table Row1,column3 write "Ashok". In first table Row2,column3 write "Jariwala". Copy both tables on second page. On second page, table(1),Row1,column3write "Ashok". and table(1),Row2,column3 write "Zariwala". In above code I change Row(4) to Row(2). Now run the code. My word page has two pages. I am suppose to get two PDF files exported to my default location. FIrst page as "Ashok - Jariwala" and second page as "Ashok - Zariwala". I only get "Ashok - Jariwala". I hope you may get my problem understand.